# translate command in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted when the below script do working, deleted special characters. But for first character in second parameter, this action is not working.

```
select translate('A@@!a123','!@#$%^&*)(_+',' ') from dual;
```

to replace `!` with space, but did not remove from string.

Comment: What is expected output string do you want?

Comment: @roya : Would suggest you to add more briefing in what is required to get you more help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is change your function to `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('A@@!a1+23', '[!@#$%^&*)(_+]', '')  
FROM dual;
```